# Boost testrunner in Eclipse fails to generate valid XML

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost-test

I am attempting to run unit tests from Eclipse on C++ code.  My Eclipse is Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).  I originally downloaded the Java Developer's version, but I've installed C/C++ plugins.  I wrote a simple class and then a boost unit test for that class.  I can compile the code both in Eclipse and on the command line to get an executable.  If I run the executable on the command line, I get this output

> Running 1 test case...
>
> *** No errors detected

So far so good.

Now if I try to run inside Eclipse, I get an error.  At first it appeared that my test was not running at all.  In the "C/C++ Unit" tab, I got a red bar on the right side of the screen, no information where I should be seeing individual test results, and a message "XML parse error: Premature end of file" in small text right below the row of tabs.  By stopping in the debugger, I was able to see that I'm victim of a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484942).  Basically there's some incompatibility between Eclipse and boost testrunner, where one is specifying XML and the other xml (different case) for the format.  I tried this work-around mentioned in the discussion about the bug at that link:

> As a workaround you can add following arguments in the unittests' run configuration:
>
> --output_format=XML --log_level=all --report_level=no --
>
> Eclipse's test runner appends it's arguments to these. Arguments after -- are passed on to your test script and ignored by Boost.Test.

With that in place, I still have problems, but the problem is different depending on whether I run with debugging or not.  Without debugging, the result is the same as noted above.  With debugging, I get information about my test - noting that it ran and passed - on the left side of the "C/C++ Unit" tab but I still get the red bar indicating a failure. The small text in this case says: "XML parse error: Content is not allowed in tailing section."

The bug noted above appears to be about 2 yrs old, although the discussion has activity as recently as last month.  I guess there's some other work around?  It seems likely that the community has been running tests in the intervening two years!

I tried updating Eclipse via Help -> Check for Updates.  That did not improve my situation.  I suspect that other information may be valuable to help, but I'm not sure what to provide.  I'll watch comments and update if / where I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reluctantly, I upgraded to the Neon.2 release of Eclipse. The underlying bug is still present, as described in my question, but the work-around noted works in that release.  Copying that down from the question for completeness:

> As a workaround you can add following arguments in the unittests' run configuration:
>
> --output_format=XML --log_level=all --report_level=no --
>
> Eclipse's test runner appends it's arguments to these. Arguments after -- are passed on to your test script and ignored by Boost.Test.

Would have been nice if this worked in Mars as well since upgrading is a bit of a hassle - especially with support for multiple development languages - but at least I can move on.  Probably would have had to upgrade at some point in any case.